# Passing URL parameter into hidden field in form

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script (I got it off a blog, actually) to pass URL parameters like utm_campaign and utm_source into hidden fields in a form. But the script isn't executing and in browser console, it's showing error. But I am not a developer so I don't really know how to fix it :(

This is the code:

```
<script>
// Parse the URL to get the required field values

function getUtmParamByName(utmname) {

    utmname = utmname.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");

    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),

    results = regex.exec(location.search);

    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getUtmParamByName('utm_source');
var medium = getUtmParamByName('utm_medium');
var campaign = getUtmParamByName('utm_campaign');
var content = getUtmParamByName('utm_content');
var term = getUtmParamByName('utm_term');
// Put the variable names into the hidden fields in the form.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#form-field-utm_source').val(source);
    $('#form-field-utm_medium').val(medium);
    $('#form-field-utm_campaign').val(campaign);
    $('#form-field-utm_content').val(content);
    $('#form-field-utm_term').val(term);
}
</script>
```

Please help!

TIA

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: Hi @FissureKing, will do that now.

Comment: @FissureKing, I modified the ending with ); and one error is gone. Now second error is this:

    Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at ?utm_source=instagram:109

Comment: Okay, that looks like you don't have jQuery referenced. Do you have a script tag for that above this one?

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to jQuery library in the header page section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, after doing that, script errors in console went away. However, it’s still not passing URL parameters into the hidden form fields. :(

Comment: @SamuelFaith try to move all the variables var source = getUtmParamByName('utm_source') inside the $( document ).ready(function() {

Comment: Hi @mbadeveloper, I just did it. It still won't put any values from URL parameter into the specified form fields. I am pulling my hair out now.

Comment: @SamuelFaith Its difficult to guess what happened with the code that you provide try to debug it and find what is the value of location.search

Comment: the URL is www.ineeeedthis.xyz, if it'd help?

Comment: You don't have parameters what is expect is  www.ineeeedthis.xyz?utm_source=aa&utm_medium=bb

Comment: I actually tried with URL parameters. It doesn't populate the form fields. I gave you the URL without the parameters because I thought you'd like to see the code there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out!. Instead of:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

I changed it to:

```
$(function() {
```